# Retrieving Rain Current Rate from 2 MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, relational-database

I have two SQL tables:

- pluviometers (**id**, lat, lng, desc)
- rains (**id**, pluviometer_id, date, value)

Table fields and structure are self-explanatory.

The only remarkable point is that 'rains' is a **cumulative** table, i.e., *value* field is the cumulative amount of rain, and respective *dates* are just the moments when *value* increases.

With all of that in mind, I want to execute a SQL query which obtains the list of all pluviometers and their attributes plus one field, with the rain amount **from a given date to the query execution time**.

My best try, so far:

```
    SELECT 
    pluviometers.*, 
    lastDate, 
    lastValue,
    firstDate,
    firstValue,
    rain = 
    CASE firstDate
        WHEN NULL THEN 0
        ELSE (lastValue - firstValue) / (lastDate - firstDate)
    END

FROM pluviometers

LEFT JOIN (

    SELECT 
        h.pluviometer_id AS pid,
        MAX(h.date) AS lastDate, 
        h.value AS lastValue

    FROM rains h

    LEFT JOIN (

        SELECT 
            h2.pluviometer_id AS pid2,
            MIN(h2.date) AS firstDate, 
            h2.value AS firstValue 

            FROM rains h2
            WHERE h2.date > ###### GIVEN DATE ######

            GROUP BY pid2
            ORDER BY pid2 ASC

        ) AS p2 ON pid2 = h.pluviometer_id

    GROUP BY pid
    ORDER BY pid ASC

) AS p ON pid = pluviometers.id

GROUP BY pluviometers.id
ORDER BY pluviometers.id ASC
```

So far, I get a #1054 - Unknown column 'firstDate' in 'field list' error from the server.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firstDate` and also `firstValue` are selected from `h2` to create the result set `p2`, but you don't select `p2.firstDate` or `p2.firstValue` from the combined result set `rains h LEFT JOIN p2`.

So add them to your first sub-select clause here:

```
... SELECT 
    h.pluviometer_id AS pid,
    MAX(h.date) AS lastDate, 
    h.value AS lastValue,
    p2.firstDate,
    p2.firstValue

FROM rains h ...
```

This will make them visible to the outer select clause at the top.

Also, change the syntax for selecting the `rain` field:

Not

```
rain = 
    CASE firstDate
        WHEN NULL THEN 0
        ELSE (lastValue - firstValue) / (lastDate - firstDate)
```

but instead

```
CASE firstDate
    WHEN NULL THEN 0
    ELSE (lastValue - firstValue) / (lastDate - firstDate)
END AS rain
```

Comment: Thanks! Solved that problem, but now I get a #1054 - Unknown column 'rain' in 'field list'... Any ideas?

Comment: @andcl85 I've updated the answer with a fix for this issue too.